# Is it possible set my Excel Userform Combo box to begin narrowing the fields while data is entered?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

VBA Newbie here. 
I have searched high and low for this answer, and even come across other questions very similar to mine, but cannot get an answer. So I am hoping that this is my lucky day. 
I have a Userform in excel that has Four combo boxes. Each combo box has a drop down with several choices. In two of these boxes, there are many business names and a lot of these names are similar. I was wanting to have the feature where are the data was being typed into the box, it would begin to narrow the options. EXAMPLE: if I type "heating and air" it begins to only show items in the list that include that word or phrase. 
Is this a properties change in the box, or a code written, or something else? 
Please help- I am stumped and no one seems to have the answer.

Very grateful-
Excel Newbie

Comment: Default behavior (I am using Excel 2013) is that if I begin typing it will autocomplete for me.  But I am assuming you want something a bit better than autocomplete?  Like you want to find a phrase even if you don't know the beginning of it?  For example: I added a combobox of colors.  If I started typing `Gr` it correctly selected `Green` however if I typed `een` it does not find `Green`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is very possible. All you have to do is create a sub that populates that combo box, set it up so that when adding it checks the value of the box for example if it was the basic typing example. basic format. This assumes the possible values are stored in an array. This would add any item that has the string entered in it. (in any position)

```
For I = 0 to Number of Values
     If instr(Value(I), ComboBox.Text) > 0 then
         add item
     endif
next
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around a bit and came up with something to get you started.  This basically functions as an "auto search".  It is not autocomplete because it will search entire terms, not just terms which begin with whatever you've typed in.  Basically I assume you have a range of cells (in this example cells `A2:A121`) that have the date for your drop down in it.

**Setup**

Add a new generic module (I named mine `GlobalVars` and add the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public IgnoreChange As Boolean
Public RangeOfData As Variant
```

**The Code**

Open the code to your UserForm.

Add the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        RangeOfData = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A2:A121").Value)
        IgnoreChange = False
End Sub
```

Be sure to update `A2:A121` and `Sheet1` (I am using code name, but `Worksheets("Sheet1")` would work just as well) to point to the data which contains your combobox choices.

Now, the meat of the job is handled in the `Combobox_Change` event

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

        If Me.ComboBox1.Text = vbNullString Then
                Me.ComboBox1.Clear
                SendKeys ("{Enter}")
        End If

        If Me.ComboBox1.TextLength > 2 Then

                Dim i As Long, j As Long

                If IgnoreChange = False Then
                Me.ComboBox1.Clear
                SendKeys ("{Enter}")
                DoEvents 'Bug with NumLock
                For i = LBound(RangeOfData) To UBound(RangeOfData)
                        If UCase(RangeOfData(i)) Like "*" & UCase(Me.ComboBox1.Text) & "*" Then
                                Me.ComboBox1.AddItem RangeOfData(i)
                        End If
                Next i

                Me.ComboBox1.DropDown

                End If

        End If
        IgnoreChange = False
End Sub
```

Be sure to change `ComboBox1` to the name of your combobox control.

Basically, what this does is it handles user input when it reaches two characters or longer.  The code will search through your input data range and then return results that match the string as the user is entering it.  The results is like a suggestions box.

I should note that with this method, the combobox is NOT pre-populated with data, so users must begin typing something into the combobox.

Additionally, I added the following code to handle the backspace key:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
        If KeyCode = 8 Then
                IgnoreChange = True
        End If
End Sub
```

Again be sure to change `ComboBox1` as appropriate.

For my example, I loaded all 120 crayola crayon colors into a spreadsheet (that is what is in Sheet1 from A2:A121).

Here is example output for when I start typing, first I input `blu`:[image]

As you can see I am getting all values that contain `blu`, including those that don't start with `blu` such as Cadet Blue or Midnight blue.

As another example, I will search for `flower`

[image]

So as you can see, instead of being a combobox with 120 static options, it is updated based on what the user types and tied to a list of values in your cells.

I did notice that `SendKeys` sometimes toggled my NumLock, this is a known issue.  The point of that line is to collapse the drop down after the user deletes all of the text or continues texting so as to "refresh" the auto-generated list.